# TeeChart ActiveX CodeUTF8String and DecodeUTF8String

Tags: activex, teechart

I am trying to update from TeeChart ActiveX 7 to TeeChart 2012/2013. My old TeeChart files were written with a version that saved Unicode strings coded with a "@U#" prefix. I wanted to use the DecodeUTF8String in the new "real-Unicode" version to convert these saved strings to ordinary Unicode strings. However, both the code and decode functions appear to have no effect. Am I missing something? How can I deal with this problem?
Would be great if I could get some help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Being real unicode, these functions don't convert the texts anymore. However, I understand in cases like yours it could still be necessary to do that decodification.

We'll study if we can offer some built-in way to decode the strings coded in older versions. In the meanwhile, the only way I can think on is to manually replace in your TeeChart .tee files (save them as text, not as binary) the coded strings with decoded strings, so you'll have unicode tee files that should be correctly imported in newer TeeChart ActiveX versions.